# Restrict from storing cookies in sharedHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: ios, nshttpcookie

Can we restrict from storing cookies in sharedHTTPCookieStorage by default?

I am using other approach for session authentication and don't want cookies to be sent to server on each server request. Currently I read all cookies from sharedHTTPCookieStorage and delete them manually after Login.

It would be better if they are not set automatically by default at first place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this. But I worked on some apps that need to cache zero to none info for security reasons. 
I think that you could go with a combined approach.
Defining a no-caching policy to responses, on NSCachedURLResponse and also intercepting calls with your own NSURLProtocol.
[Here's some info on the whole URL Loading system on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

I hope it helps a little! Good luck!